# Cosmos DB: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Accessing CosmosClient after it is disposed is invalid

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am getting below exception for Web Api App Service:

> Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer EventId: 2 RequestId: 8000001b-0000-6000-b63f-84710c7967bb
> RequestPath: /api/notification/RetrieveNotifications SpanId:
> 93ff3a8b0da39d4f TraceId: 730bf862b1072a409c402c3b795488ad ParentId:
> 251526087660f84b Connection ID "6917529029251694618", Request ID
> "8000001b-0000-6000-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was
> thrown by the application. Exception:
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not
> indicate success: InternalServerError (500); Substatus: 0; ActivityId:
> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; Reason: (Cannot access a
> disposed object. Object name: 'Accessing CosmosClient after it is
> disposed is invalid.'.); ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot
> access a disposed object. Object name: 'Accessing CosmosClient after
> it is disposed is invalid.'. at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.ThrowIfDisposed() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.ThrowIfDisposed[T](T input)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.get_DocumentClient() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient.get_DocumentClient() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.ProcessMessageAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.AbstractRetryHandler.ExecuteHttpRequestAsync(Func`2
> callbackMethod, Func`4 callShouldRetry, Func`4
> callShouldRetryException, ITrace trace, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.AbstractRetryHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(String
> resourceUriString, ResourceType resourceType, OperationType
> operationType, RequestOptions requestOptions, ContainerInternal
> cosmosContainerCore, FeedRange feedRange, Stream streamPayload,
> Action`1 requestEnricher, ITrace trace, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosQueryClientCore.ExecuteItemQueryAsync(String
> resourceUri, ResourceType resourceType, OperationType operationType,
> Guid clientQueryCorrelationId, FeedRange feedRange,
> QueryRequestOptions requestOptions, SqlQuerySpec sqlQuerySpec, String
> continuationToken, Boolean isContinuationExpected, Int32 pageSize,
> ITrace trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.NetworkAttachedDocumentContainer.MonadicQueryAsync(SqlQuerySpec
> sqlQuerySpec, FeedRangeState`1 feedRangeState, QueryPaginationOptions
> queryPaginationOptions, ITrace trace, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.PartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.BufferedPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.PrefetchAsync(ITrace
> trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.BufferedPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.GetNextPageAsync(ITrace
> trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.PartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.CrossPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CrossPartition.Parallel.ParallelCrossPartitionQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.LazyQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.NameCacheStaleRetryQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CatchAllQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.ThrowIfDisposed() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.ThrowIfDisposed[T](T input)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.get_DocumentClient() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient.get_DocumentClient() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.ProcessMessageAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.AbstractRetryHandler.ExecuteHttpRequestAsync(Func`2
> callbackMethod, Func`4 callShouldRetry, Func`4
> callShouldRetryException, ITrace trace, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.AbstractRetryHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(String
> resourceUriString, ResourceType resourceType, OperationType
> operationType, RequestOptions requestOptions, ContainerInternal
> cosmosContainerCore, FeedRange feedRange, Stream streamPayload,
> Action`1 requestEnricher, ITrace trace, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosQueryClientCore.ExecuteItemQueryAsync(String
> resourceUri, ResourceType resourceType, OperationType operationType,
> Guid clientQueryCorrelationId, FeedRange feedRange,
> QueryRequestOptions requestOptions, SqlQuerySpec sqlQuerySpec, String
> continuationToken, Boolean isContinuationExpected, Int32 pageSize,
> ITrace trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.NetworkAttachedDocumentContainer.MonadicQueryAsync(SqlQuerySpec
> sqlQuerySpec, FeedRangeState`1 feedRangeState, QueryPaginationOptions
> queryPaginationOptions, ITrace trace, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.PartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.BufferedPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.PrefetchAsync(ITrace
> trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.BufferedPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.GetNextPageAsync(ITrace
> trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.PartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.CrossPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator`2.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CrossPartition.Parallel.ParallelCrossPartitionQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.LazyQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.NameCacheStaleRetryQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Pipeline.CatchAllQueryPipelineStage.MoveNextAsync(ITrace
> trace) --- Cosmos Diagnostics
> ---{"name":"NoOp","id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","component":"Unknown","caller
> info":{"member":"NoOp","file":"NoOp","line":9001},"start
> time":"12:00:00:000","duration in
> milliseconds":0,"data":{},"children":[]}

I am using Cosmos DB and creating the instance in the startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private const string CosmosDBEndpoint = "CosmosDBEndpoint";
        private const string CosmosDBAuthKey = "CosmosDBAuthKey";

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            RegisterCosmosClient(services, Configuration);
            services.AddTransient(typeof(ICosmosDbRepository<>), typeof(CosmosDbRepository<>));

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Shell Fleet Hub Notifications WebApi", Version = "v1", });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSwagger();

           
        }

        private static void RegisterCosmosClient(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            string cosmosDbEndpoint = configuration[CosmosDBEndpoint];
            string cosmosDbAuthKey = configuration[CosmosDBAuthKey];


            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(s => new CosmosClient(cosmosDbEndpoint, cosmosDbAuthKey,
                new CosmosClientOptions { AllowBulkExecution = true }));
        }
    }
```

Cosmos DB Repository:

```
public class CosmosDbRepository<T> : ICosmosDbRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public static readonly string CollectionId = GetAttributeCosmoDbCollection<T>(typeof(T));
        private readonly CosmosClient _client;
        private Container _container;
        private Database _database;
        private const string CosmosDbId = "CosmosDbId";
        private readonly IGetConfigurationSettings _configurationSettings;

        public CosmosDbRepository(CosmosClient client, IGetConfigurationSettings configurationSettings)
        {
            _client = client;
            _configurationSettings = configurationSettings;
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync();
                await CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync();
            }).Wait();
        }

        public async Task<ItemResponse<T>> CreateItemAsync(T item, string partitionKeyValue)
        {
            return await _container.CreateItemAsync<T>(item, new PartitionKey(partitionKeyValue));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(string queryString)
        {
            var query = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(new QueryDefinition(queryString));

            List<T> results = new List<T>();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();

                results.AddRange(response.ToList());
            }
            return results;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDesc, int takeCount = -1)
        {
            var criteria = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true,
                continuationToken: null,
                new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = takeCount })
                .Where(predicate)
                .OrderByDescending(orderByDesc)
                .ToFeedIterator();

            var query = criteria;

            var results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                if (takeCount > -1 && results.Count >= takeCount) break;
                results.AddRange(await query.ReadNextAsync());
            }

            return results;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDesc, string partitionKey, int takeCount = -1)

        {
            var criteria = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(allowSynchronousQueryExecution: false,
                continuationToken: null,
                new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) })
                .Where(predicate)
                .OrderByDescending(orderByDesc)
                .ToFeedIterator();

            var query = criteria;

            var results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                if (takeCount > -1 && results.Count >= takeCount) break;
                results.AddRange(await query.ReadNextAsync());
            }

            return results;
        }

        public Task<ItemResponse<T>> UpdateItemAsync(string id, T item)
        {
            return _container.ReplaceItemAsync<T>(item, id);
        }

        private async Task CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            _database = await _client
                .CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(_configurationSettings.Get(CosmosDbId));
        }

        private async Task CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            _container = await _database
                .CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(new ContainerProperties(CollectionId, $"/{GetPartitionKeyAttributeCosmoDbCollection(typeof(T))}"));
        }

        private string GetPartitionKeyAttributeCosmoDbCollection(Type t)
        {
            var attribute = (CosmoDBContainerAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(CosmoDBContainerAttribute));
            return attribute.PartitionKey;
        }

        private static string GetAttributeCosmoDbCollection<T>(Type t)
        {
            var attribute = (CosmoDBContainerAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(CosmoDBContainerAttribute));
            return attribute.Name;
        }
    }
```

Below is how I am using this repository:

```
public class RetrieveUserSubscriptionQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<RetrieveUserSubscriptionQuery, ResultDto>
    {
        private readonly ICosmosDbRepository<UserSubscriptions> _userSubscriptionRepository;

        public RetrieveUserSubscriptionQueryHandler(ICosmosDbRepository<UserSubscriptions> userSubscriptionRepository)
        {
            _userSubscriptionRepository = userSubscriptionRepository;
        }

        public async Task<ResultDto> HandleAsync(RetrieveUserSubscriptionQuery query, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Started {nameof(RetrieveNotificationQueryHandler)} with UUID:{query.UserUUId}");

            var userSubscriptions = await GetUserSubscriptions(query, logger);

            return new ResultDto
            {
                ResultType = ResultType.Success,
                Data = userSubscriptions
            };
        }
        private async Task<UserSubscriptionDto> GetUserSubscriptions(RetrieveUserSubscriptionQuery query, ILogger logger)
        {
            var dto = new UserSubscriptionDto
            {
                UserId = query.UserUUId,
                Subscriptions = new List<SubscriptionDto>(),
                UiNotifications = new List<NotificationCategoryType>(),
                EmailNotifications = new List<NotificationCategoryType>()
            };

            var userSubscriptions = await _userSubscriptionRepository
                                        .GetItemsAsync(s => s.UUID == query.UserUUId, o => o.UUID);

            if (userSubscriptions.Any())
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"subscriptions found for UUID:{query.UserUUId}");

                foreach (var userSubscription in userSubscriptions)
                {
                    if (userSubscription.Type.Equals(UserSubscriptionType.Subscription.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        foreach (var item in userSubscription.Events)
                        {
                            var notificationCategory = Utility.GetNotificationCategoryType((NotificationType)item.EventType);

                            if (item.Channels.Any(x => x == (int)ChannelType.UI) && !dto.UiNotifications.Contains(notificationCategory))
                            {
                                dto.UiNotifications.Add(notificationCategory);
                            }
                            if (item.Channels.Any(x => x == (int)ChannelType.Email) && !dto.EmailNotifications.Contains(notificationCategory))
                            {
                                dto.EmailNotifications.Add(notificationCategory);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (userSubscription.Type.Equals(UserSubscriptionType.Accounts.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        foreach (var payer in userSubscription.Payers)
                        {
                            dto.Subscriptions.Add(new SubscriptionDto
                            {
                                PayerNumber = payer.PayerNumber,
                                AccountNumbers = payer.Accounts
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"No subscriptions found for UUID:{query.UserUUId}");
            }
            return dto;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include some code for using the repository?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have upated the question. Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Not sure exactly where this is coming from, but the repository class should be registered as a singleton at least. I wrap my CosmosClient in a CosmosService class that's registered as a singleton and initialized with a simple constructor.

Comment: @NoahStahl I have registered respository as a singleton, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: If nobody has ideas here you might open an issue in SDK repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3